# Google Maps Autocomplete Province

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using Google Maps APIs guide for autocomplete:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

but it seems it is not possible to detect Italy provinces.

For instance: typing an Italian address "Caronno Pertusella, VA, Italia", I'm not able to detect "VA".

I tried add and change parameters: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

but I can not find province parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That could have been easier. I think you are looking for administrative_area_level_2. Because this levels differs from country to country you have to test, which level fits your need. Attached an example with administrative_area_level_2 ('short_name'). You may play a little bit with that, Reinhard

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Region</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
  <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search for: "Caronno Pertusella VA, Italia" = without comma before VA, you will get it. Also "Caronno Pertusella VA, It" will work. After the city comma, autocomplete await the country or country code.

By the way, why do you not just choose one of the proposals of autocomplete? If you type in "Caronno " you get as proposal: "Caronno Pertusella Varese, Italia"

Comment: I think my question it is not clear, I don't know which is the field that return province. Inside "componentForm" variable: `      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'short_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name',
        sublocality: 'long_name',
        intersection: 'long_name'
      };`